# Linker Command Failing - Undefined symbols for architecture armv7

Tags: google-maps, linker, cocoapods, google-maps-sdk-ios

I am trying to install the Google Maps Utils plugin via cocoapods so I can utilize the clustering functionality. I have followed the setup guide provided by google step by step however I am getting a build error during the linking process.
The error I get is:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture armv7: 
"_OBJC_CLASS_$_POIItem", referenced from:
  objc-class-ref in MainViewController.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture armv7
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Does anyone have a solution to this? I have tried just about everything I could find on the web.

Thanks in advance!

EDIT:

I have defined the POIItem as follows:

```
#import "ViewController.h"

#import <Google-Maps-iOS-Utils/GMUMarkerClustering.h>
#import <GoogleMaps/GoogleMaps.h>

// Point of Interest Item which implements the GMUClusterItem 
protocol.
@interface POIItem : NSObject<GMUClusterItem>

@property(nonatomic, readonly) CLLocationCoordinate2D position;
@property(nonatomic, readonly) NSString *name;

- (instancetype)initWithPosition:(CLLocationCoordinate2D)position name:(NSString *)name;

@end
```

and here is a link to the set up guide I followed: [Google Guide](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios-sdk/utility/marker-clustering#add-a-simple-marker-clusterer)

Comment: Looks like an issue with your app. What is POIItem and how is it built?

Comment: I edited my question to provide more details

Comment: Is the POIItem implementation being built?

Comment: I don't believe so? It passes everything up to the linking process then fails which makes me think it is unable to access the framework where POIItem exists.